# Getting count of contained entities

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a `Lists` entity which contains `Item` entities. I'd like to get the count of `Items` when I fetch `Lists`.

This the query I tried:

```
$lists = $this->Lists->find()
            ->contain(["Items" => function($q){
                return $q->select(["count" => $q->func()->count("*")]);
            }])
            ->all();
```

which does not work. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the answer can be found in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records).

Example code snippet:

```
$lists = $this->Lists->find();
$lists
    ->select(["Lists.id", "itemCount" => $lists->func()->count("Items.id")])
    ->matching("Items")
    ->group(["Lists.id"])
    ->all();
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness - there's also [**counter cache**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html).

Comment: Counter cache is actually exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using PHP to get the count instead of relying on a bunch of unnecessary count queries (which can hog resources quickly).

There may be a more elegant way, but I would just do the `find()`, then append the count with PHP:

```
$lists = $this->Lists->find()
    ->contain(["Items"])
    ->all();

foreach($lists as &$list) {
    $list['Items']['count'] = count($list['Items']);
}
```

(the above code is off the top of my head - take it more as pseudo code to show the idea, as there may be minor syntax issues...etc.)